# Export data from similar nodes in Xml to excel using Xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an xml document where values are generated dynamically and i need to export these data to an excel using xslt. For testing purpose I have created a sample xml:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<ucdetector>
  <!--COPY_RIGHT-->
  <statistics/>
  <markers>
    <!--Sample XML_INFO-->
    <marker>
      <description>Desc</description>
      <classRef>Test1</classRef>
      <classRef>Test2</classRef>
      <classRef>Test3</classRef>
      <markerType>Class PreferenceInitializer has 8 references</markerType>
    </marker>
  </markers>
  <problems/>
</ucdetector>
```

The xslt is as follows:-

= tab = new line -->

```
<!-- First line: about -->
<xsl:value-of
    select="concat('Report', '&#x9;', /ucdetector/statistics/abouts/about[@name='reportCreated']/value, '&#xA;', '&#xA;')" />
<!-- Second line: header -->

<xsl:value-of
    select="concat('Class Name', '&#x9;', 'Referring class
    name', '&#x9;', 'Class Details', '&#xA;')" />


<xsl:for-each select="/ucdetector/markers/marker">
    <xsl:variable name="vars">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="classRef" />
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:value-of
        select="concat(description, '&#x9;', $vars, '&#x9;', markerType, '&#xA;')" />
</xsl:for-each>
```

**I was able to export all the data properly into excel except for data in tag "classRef" which appears together as "Test1Test2Test3" , but i need them separately in different columns of excel.
Can anybody provide some clue on this?**

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want the three values to be tab-separated? In which case I would be inclined to do this (in XSLT 2.0)

```
<xsl:for-each select="/ucdetector/markers/marker">
    <xsl:variable name="vars">
        <xsl:value-of select="classRef" separator="'&#x9;'"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:value-of
        select="concat(description, '&#x9;', $vars, '&#x9;', markerType, '&#xA;')" />
</xsl:for-each>
```

or in 1.0

```
<xsl:for-each select="/ucdetector/markers/marker">
    <xsl:variable name="vars">
        <xsl:for-each select="classRef">
          <xsl:if test="position()!=1"><xsl:text>&#x9;</xsl:text></xsl:if>
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:value-of
        select="concat(description, '&#x9;', $vars, '&#x9;', markerType, '&#xA;')" />
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I tried the options suggested from your side.Actually I need the values in "classRef" node not tab separated but one below the other . Please could you help with that !!

Answer (score 0):

Your question's a little unclear.  I think what you're trying to do is emit the text of all of the child elements of the `marker` element, separated by tabs, as a line of text terminated with a newline.  Is that right?

If so, I don't see any benefit of creating a variable that contains the `classRef` elements all concatenated together - you're not treating them any differently than you are the other elements.  You can just use a simple template to transform each `marker` element into an output line:

```
 <!-- It's really only worth doing this if your transform uses lots of tabs
      and newlines, which this one no longer does.  But it aids readability
      and reduces the number of typos you'll make, so it's a good habit to
      get into. -->
 <xsl:variable name="tab">&#x9</xsl:variable>
 <xsl:variable name="newline">&#xA;</xsl:variable>

 <xsl:template match="marker">
    <xsl:for-each select="*">
      <xsl:if test="position() != 1">
        <xsl:value-of select="$tab"/>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:value-of select="$newline"/>
 </xsl:template>
```

**Edit:**

Okay, the example you posted clarifies what you're looking for.  What you want is one line in the output for each `classRef` element, not each `marker` element.  Every line should have the same number of tabs, and be terminated with a newline.  But the *first* line for any given `marker` element should contain data for the non-`classRef` elements, while the remaining lines should only contain data for the `classRef` elements.

This should do the trick:

```
<xsl:template match="marker">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="classRef"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="classRef[position() = 1]">
   <xsl:variable name="current" select="."/>
   <xsl:for-each select="../*[name() != 'classRef' or . = $current]">
      <xsl:if test="position() != 1">
         <xsl:value-of select="$tab"/>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
   </xsl:for-each>
   <xsl:value-of select="$newline"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="classRef">
   <xsl:variable name="current" select="."/>
   <xsl:for-each select="../*[name() != 'classRef' or . = $current]">
      <xsl:if test="position() != 1">
         <xsl:value-of select="$tab"/>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:if test=". = $current">
         <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </xsl:if>
   </xsl:for-each>
   <xsl:value-of select="$newline"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. You are almost correct . I need text of all child elements of marker element in their appropriate columns separated by tabs. I am able to produce this output partially except for "classRef" elements which are not appearing one below other.

Comment: What character should `classRef` values be separated by?

Comment: classRef values in the xml provided above are "Test1","Test2","Test3".I need them one below other in an excel column , I think separation can be done with a new line!!

Comment: For better understanding I have uploaded a sample excel format which I am looking to achieve with the xml and xslt described above. **'Please download the sample excel from the url'** :- [link]http://www.4shared.com/document/GdMlndFR/Demo.html

Comment: @Robert - I hope you got my point.. Wud be gr8 if you cud help

Comment: @Robert. Thanks so much for your effort.  But code gave a blank output, I have posted the full code i tried above. Please do kindly recheck it!!!

Comment: @Robert . also as described in excel at the url :-[link]http://www.4shared.com/document/GdMlndFR/Demo.html... both classRef and markerType(Column - Class Details) elements should be formatted using xslt in similar manner

Comment: @Robert: **I have uploaded the modified code to following location...**[link]http://www.4shared.com/file/wXGadQ6y/text_Modified.html.. **Its producing a blank output. Cud u check it if possible?**...